# re-evaluate remote validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a radio button and a drop down list.

The drop down list is "AM, PM, N\A"

if the user ticks the radio button, they signify half day, so should select AM or PM

If the radio button is un-ticked then they should select N\A (I know this can be changed by jquery also but ignore that for now);

I have two remote validations over each of them in the model, passing the other as an additional field.

```
[Remote("IsHalfDayChange", "Remote", AdditionalFields = "AmPm", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "{0}")]
public bool IsHalfDay { get; set; }

[Remote("AmPmChange", "Remote", AdditionalFields = "IsHalfDay", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "{0}")]
public int AmPm { get; set; }
```

By default, the radio button is unticked, (full day) and the drop down is set to N\A.

If the user ticks the radio button, the remote validation correctly sees the wrong value in the drop downlist and displays an error.

If the user changes the drop down to AM or PM, the error for the radio button remains because it hasn't been re-evaluated.

How can I use jquery to re-evaluate the remote errors when either the radio button or drop down list change?

Comment: I'd suggest re-working this from a UX perspective. If the radio is unticked you automatically know that `N/A` has to be the choice, so either select it programmatically, or disable the input completely in that situation

Comment: There is not point as it has to be evaluated from am pm.  I know you can use jquery to re-evaluate thats why i said forget jquery to choose or not choose a value but thanks

Comment: You don't use jQuery to _re-evaluate_. And you don't use a `[Remote]` attribute. You create a conditional validation attribute so that the value of one property is validated on the value of the other property (and get both client **and** server side validation - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Thanks - for learning purposes, the below answer I put works perfectly.  What's is wrong with it?  bad practice? bad performance?

Comment: Just seems a lot less code...

Comment: @JQuery. It does not _work perfectly_ - for a start you do not get any server side validation and anyone can easily by pass your script and post back bad data. And what happens when a user selects one option, then changes there mind and selects another option (you have not added any validation back again)

Comment: thanks, it sill validates when you change your mind though... if you change the same one or either one they always validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save on performance you can just evaluate one on change rather than both unless you want the error to display under all

```
<script type="text/javascript" name="remoteVal_V1">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#amPmDropDownSelect").change(function () {
            //$("#isHalfDayCheckBox").removeData("previousValue").valid();
            $("#amPmDropDownSelect").removeData("previousValue").valid();
        });

        $("#isHalfDayCheckBox").change(function () {
            //$("#isHalfDayCheckBox").removeData("previousValue").valid();
            $("#amPmDropDownSelect").removeData("previousValue").valid();
        });
    });
</script>
```